# Submitting Informatica Workflows Parallely through PMCMD command

Tags: java, multithreading, unix, informatica, informatica-powercenter

How do I submit Informatica workflows to run at the same time..?

We developed a file having all the PMCMD commands for every workflow. We intend to call this file in the script that will eventually hit Workflow manager for the execution of Infa Workflows. The problem we are facing is, the workflows are running sequentially. There is no dependency between any of the workflows and can be run in parallel.

Im already using as below:

./pmcmd startworkflow -sv intg_ser -d Domain_name -u user -p welcome123 -usd Native -f SDE_ORAR1213_Adaptor -rin intg_ser SDE_ORA_InventoryLotDimension &

(followed by next pmcmd command)

'&' used to run the workflows in background.

**Is there any way to do apart from using '&'** , since i do not want to run the w/f in background. Any info of how Scheduling tools like DAC achieved this parallelism, we wanted to implement the same functionality without using any scheduling tool.

If not, can I achieve this through unix scripting itself? If so please provide me the steps.

Any **Java** related suggestions also accepted.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **nowait** mode to run multiple workflows in parallel.
If the workflow execution is in wait mode, workflow will not triggered by integration serveice until current workflow execution is completed. You can use **-nowait** command before the workflow name to ignore currently executing workflow so the multiple workflows can be executed in parallel.

Let me know in case you face any issues.

Comment: what if any of the workflows failed? Is there any way to get that information while the current execution of workflows?

Comment: You can monitor workflow in Workflow monitor right? Not sure my understanding is correct. Can you please explain clearly

Comment: Is this the only way(Using -no wait command) to execute them in parallel?

Comment: Yes I can view them in monitor. I am also thinking to make use of 'pmcmd getworkflowdetails'. Thank you @Jim Macaulay

Comment: You can also write a script to generate workflow logs and so you can monitor

Answer (score 0):

u can create a master-workflow in which u can call workflows at same time giving same trigger function and they will run parallel over monitor also.

also for performance u can use clock to run after desire time or from when workflow was triggered.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I have around 3000 workflows from different folders.